# Postgresql: How to get row type of a table as text?

Tags: postgresql

I want to do this:

```
json_populate_record(null::schematable, json)
```

But schematable is a text variable contaning `schema.table`

I have tried this:

```
json_populate_record(pg_typeof(schematable), json)
```

but `pg_typeof()` returns regtype not rowtype.

How do I get a rowtype of a dynamic text argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this, since a type name is always an identifier, and only constants (literals) can be parameters.

The only resort is to use dynamic SQL like

```
EXECUTE format('json_populate_record(null::%I, $1)', 'schematable') USING json;
```